# rhc setup login error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openshift

I got error while Openshift login through windows command prompt in rhc setup. Please look below code and give some solution.

The error shows like:

> "The OpenShift Online (Next Gen) Developer Preview is here! We will
>   not be accepting new users onto the OpenShift Online (v2) platform"
>   [image]

Comment: I think you'll need to show some code to get any answers :)

Comment: @Kris I attached the command line image. hope you understand my error.

Answer (score 3):

developer preview is no longer using rhc, use oc instead as command line tool

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html

Comment: Access to OpenShift Online (Next Gen) is still restricted, and the original platform is no longer available to new users. I guess I'll have to look for an alternative.

Comment: The link is broken